# LINQ to SQL for Oracle.ODP

Tags: .net, linq, oracle, linq-to-sql, odp.net

Does LINQ to SQL support Oracle.ODP? If not, is a similar offering from Oracle available or in the works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ to SQL only supports SQL Server. For LINQ to Oracle, you'll want [**Entities**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx), **[LINQ for nHibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.0.GA/NHibernate.Linq-1.0.0.GA-bin.zip/download)**, or [**DbLinq**](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) to name a few.

Of those, DbLinq is intended to be the closest thing to an exact port of LINQ to SQL for other databases.

Comment: I cannot find any code documentation and/or examples on using DbLinq with Oracle. Can you linq me up?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

DevArt offers a provider for Oracle with LINQ support [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/). They also provide a direct mode where there is no need to install an oracle client and support for ADO.NET Entity framework.

Comment: Try ORM from Devart - <a href="http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/">LinqConnect</a>. This product is developed closely to LINQ to SQL but but to you some additional possibilities and allows you to work with different DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to SQL doesn't support Oracle natively. There are a few 3rd party wrappers out there. Check [this](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) out...

Theres also some providers for Oracle for the ADO.NET Entity framework. See [here](http://www.devart.com/news/2008/directs475.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the lastest version of ODAC will help you.

http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm